# difference between '\' and '\\' in while using it as escape characters

Tags: java

I know that we use escape characters like `\n` for next line and `\t` for tab.
But today while working on few string I came across `\\$`.
I had to print `"nike$"` so to print it I had to modify the string as `"nike\\$"`.
I want to know what is the exact difference between `\` and `\\`.

Comment: difference between \ and \ ? there are none...

Comment: From the title I think he wanted to ask for the difference between \ and \\. If that is the question, the answer is \\ escapes the \.

Comment: After edit of the question: `"nike\\$"` will print `nike\$`. You don't need to escape the `$`

Comment: ya sorry for the error in question .  System.out.println("Brand".replaceFirst("fn", " nike$")); gives me an error but System.out.println("fn".replaceFirst("fn", " nike\\$")); doesnt .I wanted to know the reason for this

Comment: @darkHorse how is that related to ur question?

Comment: It would be better to add extra info in the question itself instead of in comments (click on the edit link under your question).

Comment: @LisaMM thanks for your suggestion . Will keep it in mind for my future questions .But now that I have scored -2 for my question , I think I have asked something very dumb . And to guys like "nafas" Thanks for making lifes of a beginners so much more miserable .

Answer (score 3):

Inside a string literal, `\` is an *escape*: The next character that follows tells us what it will do, as in your `\n` example for newline.

This means you can't put `\` in a string on its own, since it's half of an *escape sequence*. Instead, to have a `\` actually in a string, you use `\\`.

> I had to print `"nike$"` so to print it I had to modify the string as `"nike\\$"`

`"nike\\$"` will result in a string that outputs (for instance, via `System.out.println`) as `nike\$`, not `nike$`.

Your use of `\\$` suggests to me that you were feeding a regular expression pattern into something, e.g.:

```
p = Pattern.compile("nike\\$");
```

In that situation, we have two levels of escaping going on: The string literal, and the regular expression. To have a *literal* `$` in a regular expression, it has to be escaped by `\` because otherwise it's an end-of-input assertion. To get that `\$` actually to the regular expression parser when using a string literal, we have to escape the backslash in the literal so we actually have a backslash in the string for the regular expression engine to see, thus `\\$`.

Comment: I accept your explanation . Can you please address my comment as well that I have added with the question now? Thanks :)

Comment: @darkHorse: [`replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) takes a regular expression for the search string, so the second half of my answer above is why you need the `\\$` to get a literal `$` in the search string.